# How to generate WADL file using Jersey 1.7

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I created a hello world REST service and now I d like to generate the WADL file.

I looked around and saw that I can do so by calling :

```
http://localhost:8090/application.wadl
```

However I dont get anything in my case. I am using Jersey 1.7 with Eclipse Indigo and running on Apache 7

I also tried calling :

`http://localhost:8090/<myapplicattion_name>.wadl` but still no result.

Is this feature supported by Jersey 1.7? If yes what do i do wrong?

The web.xml file looks like this:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I don't know if this feature is supported by Jersey 1.7, but is there any reason why you can't try to update Jersey and see what's going to happen?

Comment: What does your `web.xml` look like?

Comment: I didnt want to migrate to Jersey 2 cause it took me some time to get Jersey 1.x working. But eventually I did updated to Jersey 2.x Still I cannot generate the WADL. I uploaded the web.xml file

Comment: Did you check `http://localhost:8090/rest/application.wadl`?

Comment: I just did, but still does not work. :(

Comment: hey I just managed to do it. so the link is:

http://localhost:8090/restfulexample/rest/application.wadl

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What is the name of your app in Apache, i.e., "context"?  Assume the name is "restApp".  Try this:

```
http://localhost:8090/restApp/application.wadl
```

Or, if you servlet mapping is:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>RESTService</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/company/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

..it would be:

```
http://localhost:8090/restApp/company/rest/application.wadl
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I figured out what the link is : localhost:8090/restfulexample/rest/application.wadl

Answer (score 2):

Its usually under this pattern:

```
http://<hostname>:<port>/<PROJECTNAME>/<servlet URL Pattern>/application.wadl
```

Say suppose if you project deployment desc(web.xml) looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-helloworld-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
                </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.example.rest.jersey</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-helloworld-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Then the url will be something like : `http://localhost:8080/JAXRS-HelloWorld/rest/application.wadl`

In my case :

```
JAXRS_HelloWorld is project name
rest is url pattern
```