# WADL generation in Java Rest Service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey

I have Developed java Rest Service(POST request) using Jersey Implementation.
I am able to execute the Rest Service using Java Rest Client.

But My Requirement is to Generate WADL for my Rest Service

I have tried the below URL in Browser to generate WADL file.But I am unable to generate WADL

http://172.16.6.11:8013/CustomerListService.wadl?detail=true

Could any one help

I am getting  **The requested resource is not available**.

Comment: Do you have any jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl=true in yours web.xml?

Comment: yes I have tried this  http://172.16.6.11:8013/CustomerListService.wadl?detail=true

Comment: I am getting The request resource is not available

Comment: CustomerListService is my application name

Comment: I am not understanding. can you please provide me the complete URL

Comment: See the examples in the answers of this question for url formats (same jersey 1.7) http://stackoverflow.com/q/19424000/4807777